createReactAgent with Firebase Memory using Langchain JS
I am trying to migrate my langchain agent to the new LangGraph and I am struggling to find out how to use firebase memory in this new agent. I didn't want to migrate, but now when I deploy my function it throws an error saying
node_modules/langchain/node_modules/@langchain/openai/dist/azure/chat_models.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@langchain/core/language_models/chat_models"' has no exported member 'LangSmithParams'.

2 import { LangSmithParams, type BaseChatModelParams } from "@langchain/core/language_models/chat_models";

I currently use FirestoreChatMessageHistory on a RunnableWithMessageHistory. How can I migrate using the new checkpoint method for memory in LangGraph? I'd be equally happy if you know how to fix the error I am getting since I don't really want to migrate right now.
